# How to remove dots from lines while drawing paint brush in iphone?

Tags: iphone, drawing, paint, cgcontextref

[image]I am using following code to create the paint brush in iphone.

```
@interface Canvas : UIImageView {
    CGPoint location;
}

@property CGPoint location;
.m file
@synthesize location;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    self.location = [touch locationInView:self];    
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];  

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size); 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    //CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);


    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    //CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    location = currentLocation;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
  //  CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);

    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    location = currentLocation;     
}
```

It's working but while drawing there are some dots after certain distance in line which is being drawn.i want to remove those dots and want smooth straight line.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same image all over again and again multiplying it on the old image, right?
I would try to use a fresh context on every touch. Then you multiply it on the existing image.
Perhaps thats the reason for the strange look?

Also you could add checks, if the start and endpoint are different.

And you should make an extra method for drawing. You have redundant code in TouchesMoved and TouchesEnded.

Comment: Even if i change mode to normal that effects come.that's not bcoz of using same image again and again.it also comes first time

Comment: so the problem only appears, if you draw with an transparent color? the solid blue line seems to be ok? you could save all positions of touchesmoved and draw the whole current line newly on every change.